# Download MP3 on click instead of opening tab

Tags: javascript, php

Currently the button below, opens the MP3 into a new tab I am interested in having it pop up a direct download portion on click.

**Example**

```
<a href="https://skyvault.co/show/audio?filename=5qpxt5E11oyHEG">Testing</a>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tng0dLs/).

Comment: Why not use the HTML 5 audio element? <audio src="https://skyvault.co/show/audio?filename=5qpxt5E11oyHEG" controls></audio>

Comment: you can download an mp3 with https://github.com/rndme/download, specifying a different name if desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the download attribute.

```
<a href="https://skyvault.co/show/audio?filename=5qpxt5E11oyHEG" download>Testing</a>
```

If you want to change the file name, as it says in the documentation of [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp):

> Specify a value for the download attribute, which will be the new filename of the downloaded file ("w3logo.jpg" instead of "myw3schoolsimage.jpg"):

Comment: Yea, I was messing with this but it doesn't really do what I want.. it downloads the file with "**Audio**" as the name, I should have been more direct with the question. I am trying to make it rename the file on download.

Comment: You can specify the filename in the download attribute.

Comment: No problem @Placeholder! Could you mark it as the answer?

Comment: Is there a tag to do this in firefox and other browsers also?

Comment: The download tag is supported by the other browsers except IE and Safari.

Comment: are you sure? When I click the link in firefox it opens to another window like it did previously?

Comment: What version of firefox are you using? On W3Schools, it says it's supported since Firefox 20.0

Comment: This opens a new tab in chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```js
        var url = "https://assets.codepen.io/4358584/Anitek_-_Komorebi.mp3"
        url += '?' + new Date().getTime()
        fetch(url, {headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}})
            .then(res => {
                return res.blob()
            })
            .then(blob => {
                let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

                var ae = document.createElement('a')
                ae.href = objectURL
                ae.download = "Accompaniment.mp3"
                ae.innerHTML = "Download"
                // document.body.appendChild(ae)
                ae.click()
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the download attribute, and you can also name the file which is downloaded (perhaps in this case, the name of the mp3 file):

```
<a href="https://skyvault.co/show/audiofilename=5qpxt5E11oyHEG" download='name_of_file.mp3'>Testing</a>
```